# Query to return one result, but have a count of other field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have multiple fields within my SQL table(Microsoft Access) and have created a form that will allow users to search for a serial number.  This search should use the value of a text box to search one field(Serial Number), but return the serial number, model of said serial number, description of said serial number and then a count of how many models are the same as the model of the serial number.

Here is the code I've been working with, it will run, but returns a logical error.

```
SELECT Assets.Sticker, Assets.Model, COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM Assets
WHERE Assets.[Sticker]=[Forms]![DuplicateSearch]![txtStickerSearch]
GROUP BY Assets.[Sticker], Assets.[Model]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;
```

e.g. I'm searching for the serial number 00220, I hit the search button and it returns.  The value of the count should be two(There is a total quantity of two S320 models), but it's just returning the number of results found and not the total number of models that match.

```
| Sticker | Model | Count|
|00220    | S320  | 1    |
```

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:  Found the solution with the help of user: @GMB**

```
SELECT a.Sticker, a.Model, c.Cnt
FROM Assets AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT Model, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Assets GROUP BY Model)  AS c ON c.Model = a.Model
WHERE a.Sticker=[Forms]![DuplicateSearch]![txtStickerSearch];
```

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) > 0;` makes no sense at all. Return rows that exist more than zero times. All rows do.

Comment: Duly noted, I'm extremely new to SQL within Access and am finding it doesn't work in the same manner as MySQL.  That being said it was an oversight into the code and functions with or without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `JOIN` the table with an aggregate subquery that counts the number of occurences of each model, like:

```
SELECT a.Sticker, a.Model, c.Cnt
FROM Assets a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT Model, COUNT(*) Cnt FROM Assets GROUP BY Model
) c ON c.Model = a.Model
WHERE ( a.Sticker=[Forms]![DuplicateSearch]![txtStickerSearch] )
```

Comment: Unfortunately this creates a "Enter parameter value" query form after clicking the button.  I'm trying to avoid that to cut down on end user interaction.  For some extra context on this issue, I have one form which is linked to the table where all of these records are stored.  The command button runs a macro which runs the query.  Would it be worth it to remove the text box and customize the "Enter parameter value" box to ask the user for the serial number?

Comment: @Mochida: let's try and validate the query first, before we take care of user interactions. If you replace `[Forms]![DuplicateSearch]![txtStickerSearch]` with a hardcoded value (`00220` for example), do you get the expected result?

Comment: When I change the original code I have to have '00220' I get the same result under the sticker field.  When I use the INNER JOIN code that you had posted with the '00220', it unfortunately gives me the same "Enter Parameter Value" for Cnt again.   I apologize for asking so many questions.

Comment: Your original way worked, but with one small change `SELECT a.Sticker, a.Model, c.Cnt
FROM Assets AS a INNER JOIN (SELECT Model, COUNT(*) AS Cnt FROM Assets GROUP BY Model)  AS c ON a.Model = c.Model
WHERE (((a.Sticker)=[Forms]![DuplicateSearch]![txtStickerSearch]));`  I would buy you a beer if you worked in my office, thank you very much!

Comment: @Mochida: Welcome! Note: that's a lot of parentheses... Maybe just one pair around the `WHERE` condition is enough.

Comment: Unfortunately it's added in after I save it within Access, do you know how to remove that?

Comment: @Mochida: access is maniac with parentheses anyway. If that works, then let them be...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT a.Sticker, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Assets.Sticker, Assets.Model
      FROM Assets
      WHERE Assets.[Sticker] = [Forms]![DuplicateSearch]![txtStickerSearch]
    ) as a
GROUP BY a.[Sticker];
```

If you want to count the number of different models, you don't want a separate row for each model.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting an "Undefined function 'DISTINCT' in expression" Error When I try to run this.  Does MS-Access allow for the use of DISTINCT?

Comment: @Mochida . . . It does in a subquery.  It doesn't in `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, but I changed the answer when I absorbed the tag.